# Find basis with given vector representation

Tags: matrices, vectors

i'm trying to solve this problem. But simply I have no ideas.

Problem: 
Determine base $ B={b1,b2,b3} $ if we know that vectors $a,b,c$ are known in canonical base. Also vectors are known in base $B$. Find base $B$.

I know solution to this problem is matrix of base change. 
I tried folowing:
$S:E->B$  $ $ $ $  $ $ $ $     $S^{-1}:B->S$  But im not sure how to procced. If i try to calculate it, i get horor from equations. I think there is simpler way. 
The vectors $a,b,c$ are given but i didn't wrote it on purpose. I don't want someone to calculate it for me. Thank you for any tips in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $S$ is the square matrix whose columns are the co-ordinates of $b_1, b_2, b_3$ relative to the canonical base. Then if $a_B$ is a column vector of co-ordinates relative to base $B$, the equivalent column vector $a_C$ of co-ordinates relative to the canonical base is given by

$a_C = Sa_B$

So if the square matrix $A_B$ is the matrix whose columns are the co-ordinates of $a,b,c$ relative to base $B$ and $A_C$ is the equivalent matrix of co-ordinates relative to the canonical base then

$A_C = SA_B$

If you are given the co-ordinates of $a,b,c$ relative to both bases then you know $A_B$ and $A_C$, so you can find $S$ from

$S=A_C(A_B)^{-1}$

Once you khave found $S$ then you can read off the co-ordinates of $b_1, b_2, b_3$ relative to the canonical base, since these are just the columns of $S$.

Note that $(A_B)^{-1}$ will only exists if $a,b,c$ are linearly independent. If $a,b,c$ are not linearly independent then you do not have enough information to find base $B$.

Comment: But i think it should be:   $A_c=A_bS$ ? then $S=A_c(A_b)^{-1}$.

Comment: For matrix of base change i think it should be:  $ S:A->B$  then$ A=BS$

Comment: @techno If you construct $A_C, A_B$ and $S$ from row vectors instead of column vectors then you have $A_C = A_BS$ and $S=(A_B)^{-1}A_C$. In effect, you have transposed all of the matrices, and also reversed the order of products.

Comment: I understand. My aproach was incorect, if i returned base doing my way i will probably get zero points.